# How do I get two textviews from recycler view in email intent?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-recyclerview

As you can see looking at some parts of my code I'm very new to Android and Java, but as bad as the code looks to the pro guys, it’s doing what I want it to do so far (I’m sure I’ll get there…lol). I have a custom adapter with a recycler view. There are some text views. I also have a bottom menu with an email button and I would like to use 2 of the views (R.id.brand_name & R.id.cases_text_view) and sent them as text in an email intent.  The bottom menu and the email intent is working where it is, but I don’t how to call the two text views into the EXTRA_TEXT. Please help me out.
Just one more thing: thank you to all you guys, I wouldn't have been so far with this app if it weren't for this website and all your help. I really appreciate it.

Here is the class with the bottom menu and email intent:

```
                  public class BlackLabel extends brands {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
//private String modelArrayList;
//private Context ctx;
public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
//private Button btnnext;

// supossing to have an image called ic_play inside my drawables.

public String[] brandlist = new String[]{
        "Black Label 340ml NRB (85023)",
        "Black Label 330ml Cans (85736)",
        "Black label 500ml Cans (85023)",
        "Black Label 440ml NRB (86798)",
        "Black Label 330ml RB (85556)",
        "Black Label 750ml RB (85021)",
        "Black Label 340ml NRB 12 Pack (87009)",
        "Black Label 500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)"};

public int[] pallet_size = {
        84,
        127,
        81,
        80,
        120,
        70,
        132,
        90};

public int[] myimage = {
        R.drawable.black_label,
        R.drawable.brutal_fruit,
        R.drawable.castle_lager,
        R.drawable.flying_fish,
        R.drawable.castle_lite,
        R.drawable.hansa,
        R.drawable.lion_lager,
        R.drawable.milk_stout};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.order_by_brand);
    setTitle("Black Label");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    modelArrayList = getModel();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
}
private ArrayList<Model> getModel() {
    final ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        final Model model = new Model();
        model.setNumber(0);
        model.setNumber2(0);
        model.setImage(myimage[i]);
        model.setBrand(brandlist[i]);
        model.setPallet_size(pallet_size[i]);
        list.add(model);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_Bar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(

            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.ic_home:
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(BlackLabel.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            break;

                        case R.id.ic_clear:
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(BlackLabel.this, BlackLabel.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                            break;

                        case R.id.ic_email:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:who@where.co.za"));
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Please place order for....");
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here I want some text from the adapter.");
                                startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
}
    return list;
     }}
```

And here is my Custom Adapter:

```
             public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context ctx;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber()));
    holder.tvPallet_size.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getPallet_size()));
    holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber2()));
    holder.tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber()));
    holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber2()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected Button btn_cases_plus, btn_cases_minus, btn_pallets_plus, btn_pallets_minus;
    protected ImageView tvImage;
    private TextView tvBrand, tvCases,tvPallets, tvPallet_size;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvBrand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
        tvImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);
        tvCases = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
        tvPallet_size = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
        tvPallets = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
        btn_cases_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.casePlus1);
        btn_cases_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caseMinus1);
        btn_pallets_plus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsPlus1);
        btn_pallets_minus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.palletsMinus1);

        btn_cases_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_cases_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cases_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_plus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_plus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_minus.setTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_minus_view, itemView);
        btn_pallets_plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pallets_minus.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    // onClick Listener for view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == btn_cases_plus.getId()){

            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_plus_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tvCases.getText().toString()) + 1;
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);

        } else if(v.getId() == btn_cases_minus.getId()) {

            View tempview = (View) btn_cases_minus.getTag(R.integer.btn_cases_minus_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tvCases.getText().toString()) - 1;
            if (number == 0 || number <0) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"You cannot order less than one case", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                return;
            }
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);

        }  else if(v.getId() == btn_pallets_plus.getId()) {

            View tempview = (View) btn_pallets_plus.getTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_plus_view);
            TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) + 1;
            tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(tvPallet_size.getText().toString());
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(number2));
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber2(number2);

        }   else if(v.getId() == btn_pallets_minus.getId()) {

            View tempview = (View) btn_pallets_minus.getTag(R.integer.btn_pallets_minus_view);
            TextView tvPallets = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_text_view);
            TextView tvCases = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            TextView tvPallet_size = (TextView) tempview.findViewById(R.id.pallets_size);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) - 1;
            tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(number));
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(tvPallets.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(tvPallet_size.getText().toString());
            tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(number2));
            if (number == 0 || number <0) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"You cannot order less than one pallet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber(number);
            modelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setNumber2(number2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put text from R.id.brand_name & R.id.cases_text_view views in intent? "intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here I want some text from the adapter.");" ?

Comment: Yes Anton, I want to put values from two textviews (R.id.brand_name & R.id.cases_text_view ) into that intent, but I don't know how to call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:who@where.co.za"));
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Please place order for....");
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here I want some text from the adapter.");
                                startActivity(intent);
```

Try to make next thing. Firstly, I don't really know why you didn't finish loop after this part of code but ok let's work with it.

```
 private ArrayList<Model> getModel() {
    final ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        final Model model = new Model();
        model.setNumber(0);
        model.setNumber2(0);
        model.setImage(myimage[i]);
        model.setBrand(brandlist[i]);
        model.setPallet_size(pallet_size[i]);
        list.add(model);
```

So here in every iteration of loop you got model object which you setting properties. So you could get data just from the model like `model.getBrand()`. I don't know what is  "cases"(R.id.cases_text_view)  in you app but i think it's set here

```
 model.setNumber(0);
        model.setNumber2(0);
```

So just get this number like

```
model.getNumber();  model.getNumber2(0);
```

So what is in the end:

You should make 3 "get" methods for your model class returning "String" type

```
getBrand()
getNumber()
getNumber2()
```

Then just add next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
String extraData = model.getBrand() + getNumber() getNumber2();
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:who@where.co.za"));
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Please place order for....");
                                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraData);
                                startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it would help you! ask if anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the right answer. It was in front of me all the time. I made good progress, at least it is showing something now, although just the last product on the arraylist, but not not all of them.

Comment: I've done this now, but I'm not sure where to put it.
                    model.getBrand();
                    model.getNumber();
                    model.getNumber2();

                   class Model {
                    private String brand;
                    private int number2;

                public String getBrand() {
                    return brand;
                }
                public int getNumber2() {
                    return number2;
                }
            }
Thank you again very much.

Comment: give me the code of you model class and i would help you.

Comment: I hope you can get to that in that way.

Comment: model.getBrand();
                          model.getNumber();
            model.getNumber2();

            class Model {
                private String brand;
                private int number2;

                public String getBrand() {
                    return model.getBrand();
                }
                public int getNumber2() {
                    return model.getNumber2();
                }
            }

Comment: yepp you made all right in model class i think. Is it all working ok now?

Comment: It just fills the email with the last item in the list, not all 8.

Comment: If you look list it just takes this one: 
Black Label 500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)
And the amount of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass those two values of views to the main activity 
1. Create a method with 2 parameters  in your activity
2. Set click listener on your list and onClick just call that method of your recycle view with view parameters.Inside your onClick method write
((your_activity_name)context).methodName(parameters here);

Hope this will help you

Thanks!!!

Comment: Anamica thank you, I see what you mean, I've tried for two days now and can't get right. Can you maybe give me a few more pointers or an example . Big big please. Thank you.

Comment: Can u give me ur method so that I can help u more.

Comment: public void submitOrder(View view) {
            EditText textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
            String naam = textName.getText().toString();
            EditText textQuant = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.cases_text_view);
            String hoeveel = textQuant.getText().toString();
and 
        private String createOrderSummary(String naam, String hoeveel) {
            String orderMessage = "Brand" + naam;
            orderMessage += "Quantity" + hoeveel;
            return orderMessage;
        }
then I would call orderMessage in the intent..

Comment: But it gives me "Cannot resolve symbol 'findViewById(int)". That's problem 1. and second in the mainActivity if I want to add orderMessage in the intent:
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, orderMessage);
it also tells me it cannot resolve symbol there.
So even if I can fix the findViewById thing, I still don't know how to call it in my intent.
Hope this is enough for to see what I'm trying, and maybe you can help me please. 
Thank you again.

Comment: Did you typed everything or copied from your code..because there is a typo mistake there

Comment: I copied it, but I did saw the findViewByID and changed it to findViewById. But I think I fixed that error by adding view.findViewById in front of it. Now its just to call the orderMessage to the mainActivity into the intent. I'm thinking of doing that also with an intent. Will it work?

Comment: private String createOrderSummary(String naam, String hoeveel) {
            String orderMessage = "Brand" + naam;
            orderMessage += "Quantity" + hoeveel;
            return orderMessage;

            Intent intent4= new Intent(CustomAdapter, BlackLabel.class);
            intent4.putExtra("key",orderMessage);
            startActivity(intent4);
        }

Comment: That's how I try it, but it tells me with CustomAdapter "Expression Expected" and with startActivity it says "Cannot resove symbol". Did I put the intent in the wrong place?  Thanks for your time so far to look at it.

Comment: Are you trying to call the intent from adapter??

Comment: No. I will call it from the mainActivity. I'm just creating the first part of the intent in the adapter. I need the value orderMessage in the mainActivity . 
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(YourActiivityName,NextActivity.class); intent.putExtras("key","value");startAcitivity(intent);

Comment: My code looks like this now:
        public void submitOrder(View view) {
            EditText textName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
            String naam = textName.getText().toString();
            EditText textQuant = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.cases_text_view);
            String hoeveel = textQuant.getText().toString();

Comment: String orderMessage = createOrderSummary(naam, hoeveel);
        }
        private String createOrderSummary(String naam, String hoeveel) {
            String orderMessage = "Brand" + naam;
            orderMessage += "Quantity" + hoeveel;
            return orderMessage;

            Intent intent4= new Intent(CustomAdapter, BlackLabel.class);
            intent4.putExtra("key",orderMessage);
            startActivity(intent4);
        }

Comment: Write your class_name.this  in place of CustomAdapter

Comment: My class_name is CustomAdapter.

Comment: use CustomAdapter.this

Comment: You are not extending your class with AppCompatActivity

Comment: No I'm extending it with:
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>

Comment: Hope I fixed that problem. 
I had this on top: 
private Context ctx;
So I made it:
Intent intent4= new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), BlackLabel.class);

Comment: So the error is wrong, now I just have to start the Activity. 
It tells me it cannot resolve method. 
on this line:
startActivity(intent4);